# Writing a character counter using for loop & switch statement

Tags: c, for-loop, char, switch-statement

I've been trying to write a pretty simple character counter that will take in a string and return how many of each character was used.

For some reason, whenever it gets to counting the letter 'C' and beyond it breaks, and I can't figure out why. It reads A's and B's fine.

I know I'm likely doing this in a really inefficient way but I've tried doing it with more loops and it still has the same problem. So I thought I'd do it as simply as possible until I found out whats causing it.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
char str[255];
int chCount[25];

printf("Please enter a string (255 character max): ");
scanf("%[^\n]", str);

for(int x = 0; str[x] != '\0'; x++) {
    if((str[x] >= 65 && str[x] <= 90) || (str[x] >= 97 && str[x] <= 122)) {
        switch(str[x]) {
            case 65:
            case 97:
                chCount[0]++;
            break;

            case 66:
            case 98:
                chCount[1]++;
            break;

            case 67:
            case 99:
                chCount[2]++;
            break;
        }
    }
}

printf("A: %i B: %i C: %i D: %i", chCount[0], chCount[1], chCount[2], chCount[3]);

return 0;
}
```

Obviously it isn't finished, I don't want to bother writing out the cases for every single letter of the alphabet and end up with the same problem at the end of the day.

For example, if I enter "AaBbCc" I'm returned with "A: 2 B: 2: C: 1244735232" (or another huge number).

Edit: I'm incredibly stupid, it was just as I hadn't initialized the array. Changing it to  int chCount[25] = {0}; fixed everything, and I completed the program without using that lovely switch statement (with an effective if statement before it. Yes I'm mentally challenged).

Comment: The array isn't initialized. Initialize it: `int chCount[25] = {0};`.

Comment: Why have you got an if statement before the switch statement?

Comment: Also, you can calculate the index from the letter being looked at, rather than using a huge switch statement..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is not complete and you're trying to validate output for which there'e no code yet.

You're trying to print `chCount[3]` which in in essence, an uninitialized variable (of that array), so it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said,

- Instead of using magic values, like 65, 66, use character constants themselves, like `'A'`, `'Z'`..etc.
- Your `if` statement is redundant, you're already *filtering* in `switch` case labels.
- Though not essential, but you better have a `default` case to handle out-of-range values.